# Will my MPMoviePlayer run on iPad if I compile under 3.0

Tags: iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayer

I'm having lots of issues with the MPMoviePlayer lately. My app is targeted for 3.0+. So if I compile it under 3.0 will it run on an iPad? Because it doesn't work on 3.2 because of the new MPMoviePlayer changes since 3.2

Comment: They say that apps that run on the iPhone/iTouch will run on an iPad, but obviously they are not optimized for running on the iPad.  They also might look strange depending on how you do your layout (i.e. it might look really small if you have everything constrained, etc)

Comment: I know that part, but since they made a lot of changes to the mpmovieplayer I just get sound on the simulator for iPad (3.2). What I want to know is if it runs on real devices if I use and target my 3.0 code.

Comment: Not sure, but you could always check which device the movie is playing on and then play the movie with the appropriate code for that platform.

Answer (score 0):

use `#ifdef` statements

```
#ifdef IPAD
    /*  use 3.2+ MoviePlayer framework  */
#else
    /*  use 3.0 MoviePlayer framework  */
#endif
```